# sql with group by and range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, max

I have a query which uses max aggregate function to calculate reset date for a particular selection date.There is a table vp_Accrual which have effectivedate field.selection date is passed to effectivedate field and based on that using Max function, reset date is calculated.This Query gives result only for a particular selection date.It calculate a reset date based on selection date passed.

I want to modify it so that it will give me reset date for a range of dates
Below Query gives Output for one person for the date 1st Jan as follow.

[image]

We need to modify Query so that it will give result for multiple selection date instead of only one selection date.

I tried by adding addition @enddate field as effectivedate between @selectiondate and @enddate.

But I guess tha approach is not correct.

I want to pass range of date, such as 1st jan to 4th Jan, and it should give Output for each date as below

[Image is added as Link as i dont have enough Repuation Point][https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HSX1.jpg]

Below is the Query used.

```
DECLARE @selectionDate datetime

SET @selectionDate = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), DATEADD(dd, 0, CAST('01/01/2017' AS datetime)), 101)



 SELECT
    e.personnum,
    ac.name as Accrul_Code,
    @selectionDate as Selection_DATE,
    CASE
      WHEN MAX(va.effectivedate) IS NULL THEN CAST('1/1/1753' AS datetime)
      ELSE MAX(va.effectivedate)
    END AS resetdate
  FROM vp_employeev42 e WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN accrualprofile ap
    ON e.accrualprflname = ap.name
  INNER JOIN accrualprofilemm apm
    ON apm.accrualprofileid = ap.accrualprofileid
  INNER JOIN accrualrule ar
    ON apm.accrualruleid = ar.accrualruleid
  INNER JOIN accrualcode ac
    ON ac.accrualcodeid = ar.accrualcodeid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vp_accrual va
    ON va.accrualcodeid = ar.accrualcodeid
    AND e.personid = va.personid
    AND accrualtrantype IN (3, 11)
    AND va.effectivedate <= @selectionDate

  WHERE
    ac.NAME IN ('FT PTO','LOC','EPT - 5','PT PTO','EPT')
    AND va.DISQUALIFIEDSW != 1
    and e.PERSONNUM='00152'
  GROUP BY e.personnum,
           ac.name
```

Please help me with this Query

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Also it is considered rude posting links to images, transcript your table structure, data sample and expected results. It would be easy to help you.

Comment: Stackoverflow id not allowing me to add image directly,as i need to have min8mum 10 reputation point on stackoverflow.so, image is added as link.

Comment: You're not being asked for images. You're being asked for consumable test data... Create table & insert statements and the expected results based on that test data...It allows people to create and test possible solutions. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can make out, you want a Cartesian join on a fake date table that will cause your results to repeat themselves over and over, but for a different set of dates each time

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @selectionDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime
SET @selectionDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2017,1,1)
SET @endDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2017,5,1)

WITH dates ( IncDate ) AS (
SELECT @selectionDate UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(month,1,IncDate) FROM dates WHERE Incdate <= @endDate )

 SELECT
    e.personnum,
    ac.name as Accrul_Code,
    IncDate as Selection_DATE,
    MAX(COALESCE(effectivedate, CAST('1/1/1753' AS datetime)) AS resetdate
  FROM vp_employeev42 e WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN accrualprofile ap
    ON e.accrualprflname = ap.name
  INNER JOIN accrualprofilemm apm
    ON apm.accrualprofileid = ap.accrualprofileid
  INNER JOIN accrualrule ar
    ON apm.accrualruleid = ar.accrualruleid
  INNER JOIN accrualcode ac
    ON ac.accrualcodeid = ar.accrualcodeid
  CROSS JOIN dates
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vp_accrual va
    ON va.accrualcodeid = ar.accrualcodeid
    AND e.personid = va.personid
    AND accrualtrantype IN (3, 11)
    AND effectivedate <= IncDate 



  WHERE
    ac.NAME IN ('FT PTO','LOC','EPT - 5','PT PTO','EPT')
    AND va.DISQUALIFIEDSW != 1
    and e.PERSONNUM='00152'
  GROUP BY e.personnum,
           ac.name,
           IncDate
```

A few cautions though:

This query cannot generate the results you posted, but neither can yours. There's no logic at all to your example results, where your reset date is the max date that is less than the selection date but your first of February selection date somehow chooses the tenth of Jan, yet your first of march selection date chooses the eleventh of Jan.

This is totally untested; you provided no sample data, only an image of the results, and I post from an iPad, so generating test data would be incredibly laborious, typing it all in

You mix up your dates as varchar and datetime. Please be more diligent in keeping these data types separate. Always work with dates as dates, not strings. Never store dates as string. Never rely on implicit conversions between date and string

DATEFROMPARTS came along in sqlserver 2012 I think, if your sql is older than this, use convert with a format string to turn your string into a date.. do not declare selectiondate as a varchar!